# running a thread inside a class function

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I need to run some parts of my code with thread. But I got problem with accessing the variables from `run()` function. The variables (also the function arguments) needs to be defined as final, but as I do this I cannot change their value inside `run()` function. For example now variable `iv` is not accessible in `run()` method.

Is there any way I could handle this problem?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridsq, parent, false);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    final File file = new File(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath());


    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            try {
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    };

    new Thread(runnable).start();
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: You aren't reassigning the `iv` variable... It can be `final`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do here is to make `iv` final:

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
```

In this context `final` means that you cannot change reference to the object `iv` points to, but you still can call any methods of it. Also beware of creating new `Thread` for each view, I would suggest using thread pool represented by `ExecutorService` instead.

Comment: I've already done that! but now there is just an image view with no image inside it :(

Comment: @sara check the code/logcat, maybe you have some error; also you are decoding the same stream twice.